# Как запустить сайт в интернет?

Tags: html, css

Я написал сайт, купил домен и теперь надо запустить его. Как это сделать?
У меня FilleZilla и Cyberduck.

Comment: загружаешь файлы сайта на хостинг и направляешь домен на хостинг (как правило в регистратора домена меняешь ns на параметры которые даст хостер).

Answer (score 4):

Для начала нужен хостинг. Какой у Вас сайт, статический или динамический? Используются ли php, MySQL?

Статическим подойдёт бесплатный хостинг сайтов [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) или его альтернативы. [Размещение сайта](http://isizov.ru/github-kak-hosting-dlya-sajtov/), [привязка домена](http://isizov.ru/kak-dobavit-domen-k-github-pages/). Обычная загрузка по FTP на Githup Pages не реализована, требуются [базовые навыки обращения с Git](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch02.html).

Если динамический, то каковы Ваши требования к хостингу, и сколько готовы за него платить? Заявку на свободное размещение (только полезных) сайтов можно оставить, например, у [Oxnull](http://oxnull.net/invite.html). Если там не примут, а Вам хочется именно бесплатный хостинг, попробуйте выбрать из вариантов на [этом ресурсе](http://freehostsfinder.com/ftp-support-hosting.php) или [вот тут](http://www.free-webhosts.com/free-mysql-database.php), только учтите, что пользоваться ими подчас одно мучение, и лучше немного раскошелиться.

Хостинг получили, заходите в его панель управления. Где-то должны находиться данные для FTP (иногда они приходят после успешной регистрации на электронную почту) вида:

```
FTP Hostname: ftp.yourhosting.yoursite.com or 31.170.161.102
FTP Username: a7684147
FTP Passsword: вводите свой пароль при регистрации
```

Создаёте новое подключение в Cyberduck или Filezilla, номером порта указываете 21 и загружаете Ваш сайт в корневую папку. На бесплатных хостингах загрузка даже небольшого сайта может длиться часами.

Осталось привязать домен (заодно можно и почту вида `example@yoursite.ru`). Пример осуществления на GitHub Pages см. выше. Методы внесения DNS записей у различных HSP и доменных регистраторов различаются, обратитесь к справочным материалам тех, чьими услугами Вы пользуетесь. Должно получиться примерно так, как на картинке, при возникновении затруднений свяжитесь со своим регистратором.

На каждом этапе свои нюансы, о которых, предварительно погуглив, спрашивайте более конкретно. Спасибо.

[image: DNS записи]

Answer (score 1):

Ну, берешь хостинг покупаешь, коих много.. Домен подключаешь через ns-cервера хостинга (устанавливаешь в настройках домена), сайт запускается автоматом на хосте, для загрузки кода достаточно FileZilla. А если вы и этого не знаете, мне интересно как вы вообще сайт написали.

Comment: Писать сайты учат ещё со школы... Да и полуготовых можно кучу найти. Тут не было сказанно какого уровня сайт.