# Движок / сервер для сайта

Tags: cms, веб-сервер

Есть небольшой сайт, написанный на чистом html / css и парочка js анимации.
Вот страница с поиском блоков
[image: Страница с поиском блоков]
Страница блока
[image: Страница блока]
В серверном программировании вообще ничего не знаю, и отсюда вопрос: На каком языке писать движок и что учить? (если я правильно понял, это то, через что можно управлять контентом, который будет генерировать новый html страницы и т.д. я прав?) И в какую сторону мне вообще дальше смотреть?
Спасибо за понимание и ответ, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз у Вас на сайте нет ничего помимо HTML/CSS/JS, полагаю, Вам стоит подумать о создании чисто статического сайта, чьи генераторы на настоящий момент уже вполне конкурентоспособные продукты. Почему — подробно расписано в [**данной**](https://prgssr.ru/development/pochemu-generatory-staticheskih-sajtov-budut-populyarny.html) статье от Mathias Biilmann Christensen, датируемой ноябрём 2015 года — т. е. ещё вполне актуальной. Остановлюсь на двух моментах:

- **Значительно меньше проблем с безопасностью**. См. также [ответ ув-мого D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/501557/199934).
- **Скорость загрузки страниц**. «Кэширование и особенно инвалидацию кэша очень сложно правильно настроить для динамического сайта, особенно в случае распределённого кэширования», «Даже высокооптимизированный динамический сайт проигрывает в среднем в 6 раз своей статической версии», «Мы все знаем эту статистику: 57% пользователей покидают страницу, если она грузится больше 3 секунд».

Краткий обзор самых популярных генераторов статических сайтов на начало 2016 года содержится в [следующей](http://www.cossa.ru/152/119964/) статье.

Что нужно перво-наперво, я расписал в [**этом**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497239/199934) ответе. Повторяюсь: «Статическим подойдёт бесплатный хостинг сайтов [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) или его альтернативы. [Размещение сайта](http://isizov.ru/github-kak-hosting-dlya-sajtov/), [привязка домена](http://isizov.ru/kak-dobavit-domen-k-github-pages/). Обычная загрузка по FTP на GitHub Pages не реализована, требуются [базовые навыки обращения с Git](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch02.html)». Лично для меня предпочтительнее другая система [распределённого контроля версий](http://mitra.ru/events/news/website_3.html) — [Bazaar](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.1.16/ru/mini-tutorial/index.html) — но, полагаю, для начала лучше пользоваться git и GitHub, поскольку о них в сети написано куда больше.

[image: Google Trends]
*[Google Trends](https://megamozg.ru/post/10542/) по запросу “static website generator”.*

---

**Также потребуется локальный сервер.**

По причине низкого потребления оперативной памяти я пользуюсь [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/ru/), но обычно советуют [Open Server](http://open-server.ru/), реже в последнее время [Денвер](http://www.denwer.ru/). Они ориентированы на сайты на основе PHP и большая часть их функциональности при работе со статикой не будет использоваться.

Если ограничиться статикой, то можно использовать [Mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose), потребляющий очень мало ресурсов, но не готовый к большим нагрузкам и файлам.

Есть также более надёжный, функциональный, но несколько сложный в настройке [nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/). (Сложность его настройки определяется скорее объёмом требований, зато потолок его возможностей очень высок.)

Пользователи сайта должны видеть уже готовый результат, а нужно же где-то проверять изменения. Да, можно проводить тестирования на удалённом сервере, однако:

- Придётся ожидать загрузки изменений.
- Неидеальное кэширование на хостингах; после успешной загрузки какое-то время может показываться старая версия страниц.
- Отдельный сервер для тестов — это не всегда бесплатно.

Возникает вопрос: а так ли уж необходим локальный сервер, когда пишешь именно статический сайт, ведь достаточно просто открывать страницы в браузере? 3 примера, когда обычным открытием не обойтись:

- К сайту производится подключение сторонних виджетов;
- Настройка сервера (к примеру, для Apache — через конфигурационный файл `.htaccess`);
- Работа с онлайн-сервисами, некоторые из которых работают и с сайтами на локальном сервере. В частности, [**Screenfly**](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/), с помощью которого осуществляется проверка, как выглядит веб-страница на экранах различных размеров.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой ответ. На счет хостинга - домен куплен, хостинг уже есть на регру. На счет локального сервера теперь понял для чего он нужен (думал, хватит и простого открывания .html, но очевидно нет). С гитом знаком и частенько работал с ним, опыт есть. Но для данного сайта, т.к. я разрабатываю его один, думаю, он не особо пригодится.

Comment: [**1**] Домен всегда можно перепривязать к сайту на другом хостинге. // [**2**] Если Вы не используете запросы к базам данным, можно пока и не платить за хостинг, пользуясь бесплатным GitHub Pages. // [**3**] Обычно хватает простого открывания HTML-страниц в браузере. Локальный сервер нужен, например, для просмотра, как выглядят сторонние виджеты, проверки работоспособности файла `.htaccess` (если сервер — Apache) или тестирования на [Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/), как выглядит Ваша вёрстка на различных экранах.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за столько советов

Comment: [**4**] git и прочие системы управления версиями — SVN, Mercurial, Bazaar — мне нравятся особенно по двум причинам: *а)*  Синхронизация. Если накроется Ваш компьютер или удалённый сервер, то у Вас останется копия. // *б)* Сохранение истории коммитов. // *в)* Скорость. Пользуясь плагинами [**Git**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/233899/) и [**Easygit**](https://github.com/Ivanca/easygit) для Sublime Text  я затрачиваю минимальное время на загрузку изменений на сайт. // Даже если не разрабатываете что-либо совместно и Вам пока не нужны ветки, git может оказаться полезным для Вас.

Comment: Это понадобиться для backup`a получается, правильно понимаю? А если мне не хочется заливать исходники в общий доступ, придется платить за приватность там?

Comment: @Atomrr, да, за приватность придётся на GitHub приходится платить. О причинах см. [**здесь**](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Github-offer-a-private-repository-for-free).

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю в сотый раз)

Comment: @Atomrr для статических сайтов понятие исходников штука размытая, ведь весь их код в конечном счёте либо может быть загружен клиентом, либо мёртв и подлежит удалению. Поэтому для статических сайтов публикация исходников не раскрывает ничего такого, что и без того не открыто. На скрытые URL с секретной инфой рассчитывать всё равно не стоит, ибо "безопасность через неясность" сама по себе очень ненадёжна.

Comment: @D-side уже решил, что нет смысла скрывать то, что уже давно открыто в свободном доступе) Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Для раздачи статики под Windows, кстати, [народ рекомендует Mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119307/2076787). Один экзешник, закидывается в папку с сайтом, запускается, и всё.

Comment: @D-side, добавили бы свой комментарий в ответ. Если внесёте что-то ещё, никто возражать не станет :) .

Comment: @СашаЧерных вообще говоря, это существенная правка, она добавляет в ответ информацию, которой в нём не было. В авторские (не общие) ответы просто брать и вносить не стоит :) Но в этом случае буду считать, что этот комментарий выражает согласие с такой правкой :Р

Comment: @D-side, ещё пояснили бы причину отклонения правки...

Comment: @СашаЧерных та же причина, но в обратную сторону: убирание из вопроса существенной информации (намёков на технические требования к решению). То, что решения её не затрагивают, не означает, что она не имеет значения.

Comment: @D-side, на [**SublimeServer**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549406/199934) перешёл, это удобнее.

Answer (score 2):

В таком случае вам для начала необходимо изучить php (будет необходим для обращения к базе данных) и MySQL (сама база данных) и SQL (язык запроса к бд).

Могу посоветовать курсы:
https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php
https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql

К тому же, вам будет необходимо иметь локально сервер. Рекомендую этот инструмент: http://open-server.ru

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А разве хостинг не позволяет обойтись без локального сервера? И вопрос про php, он лучше подойдет чем nodejs?

Comment: Хостинг позволяет. Но если его у вас нет, то явный выход - это пользование локальным сервером. Не всегда удобно постоянно перезаливать данные на хостинг. Ничего не могу сказать про nodejs. Но факт того что php  имеет низкий порог вхождения, налицо.

Comment: @DmitryPetukhov хостинг есть. А что можете сказать про безопасность php?

Comment: @Atomrr, сейчас я свой ответ распишу. Там и про безопасность.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Давайте, был бы рад)

Comment: @Atomrr, Я могу указать на данные с официального сайта: там описаны многие проблемы(на русском). http://php.net/manual/ru/security.php

Comment: @DmitryPetukhov То, что нужно, спасибо. Не додумался про документацию, извиняйте) Значит выбирать php и не париться на счет ноды? Просто многие друзья отговаривали от него)

Comment: Выбирайте инструмент по душе, в защиту php скажу что он пользуется огромной популярностью в России и вам будет проще найти нужную информацию на своем языке.

Comment: @DmitryPetukhov тогда его и выберу, очень важный момент про низкий порог вхождения ну и на дальнейшую работу, вроде как, проще будет устроиться. Еще раз благодарю за уделенное время, вы мне очень помогли